# Random behavior of boost tokenizer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tokenizer

I have a problem with boost tokenizer, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;

static vector<std::string> tokenize(const std::string& input, const char delim) {
    std::cout << "Tokenize: " << input << std::endl;
    vector<std::string> vector;
    typedef boost::char_separator<char> TokenizerSeparator;
    typedef boost::tokenizer<TokenizerSeparator> Tokenizer;
    TokenizerSeparator separator(&delim);
    Tokenizer tokenizer(input, separator);
    Tokenizer::iterator iterator;

    for(iterator=tokenizer.begin(); iterator!=tokenizer.end();++iterator){
        std::cout << "elem found: " + *iterator << std::endl;
        vector.push_back(*iterator);
    }
    return vector;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string input = "somedata,somedata,somedata-somedata;more data;more data";
    vector<string> list = tokenize(input, ';');

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not behave consistently all the time. Some times it works, some times not when run multiple times. When it doesn't work here is one output I get:

```
Tokenize: somedata,somedata,somedata-somedata;more data;more data
elem found: some
elem found: ata,some
elem found: ata,some
elem found: ata-some
elem found: ata
elem found: more 
elem found: ata
elem found: more 
elem found: ata
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
TokenizerSeparator separator(&delim);
```

You are tokenizing based on the *address* the character was stored at rather than the value of the character.

Comment: The constructor of `char_separator<char>` wants a `const char*` as argument. It doesn't compile if I write `TokenizerSeparator separator(delim);`

Comment: @Alexandre, Most likely it wants a `"null-terminated string"`, not a single char.

Comment: As the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm) shows, `boost::char_separator<char> sep("-;|");`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Thanks, I haven't used boost yet, so I was going off of presumption.

Comment: Here is the template definition of char_separator `template <typename Char, typename Tr = BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME std::basic_string<Char>::traits_type > class char_separator {...}` So it wants a single char.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidSchwartz for the answer (see comments above).

char_separator needs a valid C string in its constructor.